Using a test dataset with zero variation in the dependent variable for binary classification problem with panel data
For a university project, I am trying to come up with a probit model that estimates the probability of recession with at a given time using a panel dataset of various economic and financial indicators.
Given the data I have and using the standard 80/20 train/test split, the value of the dependent variable (a dummy variable representing whether a recession occurred or not) would be 0 for the entire test period.
Is it theoretically possible for me to still use this test period, even though there is no variation in the dependent variable during it?
I understand that there needs to be variation in both dependent and independent variables during the training period used to estimate the model. But surely this is not a requirement for the test period since I am just using an already estimated model to make predictions, even if any predictions of a recession will be incorrect?
